# XGBoost hyper parameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I've been trying to tune the hyperparameters of an xgboost model but found through xgb's cv function that the required n_estimators for the model to maximize performance is over 7000 n_estimators at a learning rate of .6!

This is a bit ridiculous as it'd take forever to perform the rest of the hyperparameter tuning for an optimal model. The link below is the guide I'm currently following. Can anyone offer advice on how to reduce the number of n_estimators or how I can proceed with tuning without having such a high n_estimator value? Thanks!

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/#comment-110796

Comment: I've seen guides where people recommend using n_estimators = 80-200  for big datasets and 1000 for medium to small ones, but I have seen people use 3000 estimators for some huge datasets. So I'm quite confused as to how to rectify this.

Comment: might help -   https://www.kaggle.com/prashant111/a-guide-to-xgboost-hyperparameters-tuning

Comment: @avvinci ahh thanks! I've been meaning to look into hyperopt. But does that make the link I was following invalid? Since the Kaggle post seems to be doing all params at once in a bayesian search while the other guide seems to favor a hierarchical approach doing params step by step.